# .data.rel.ro+0x8 error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for android::MediaSource'

Tags: c++, gcc, android-ndk, stagefright

I cannot solve an issue while compiling my JNI source in android using ndk-build. The class which is causing error is as below:

```
class MxDataSource : public MediaSource
{
    public:
          MxdataSource();
          virtual status_t start(MetaData *params);
          virtual status_t stop();
          virtual sp<MetaData> getFormat();
          virtual status_t read(MediaBuffer **buffer, const MediaSource::ReadOption *options));
          virtual ~MxDataSource();
          void LinkMxData(MxData* data);
          void DelinkMxData();
};
```

Here, all the virtual methods are defined pure in `MediaSource` class. Now, when I compile it, I got the following errors :

```
MxDataSource.cpp(.data.rel.ro+0x8):error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for android::MediaSource'
MxDataSource.cpp(.data.rel.ro+0x18):error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for android::MediaSource'
MxDataSource.cpp(.data.rel.ro+0x54):error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for android::MediaSource'
```

I have gone through the stackoverflow links with the similar issue but cannot solve. 
Any direction will be grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you confirm if the following header files have been included in your compilation? `<media/stagefright/DataSource.h> , <media/stagefright/MediaBuffer.h>, <media/stagefright/MediaBufferGroup.h>, <media/stagefright/MediaDefs.h>, <media/stagefright/MediaSource.h>, <media/stagefright/MetaData.h>`

Comment: Can you also share your `Android.mk` file for `frameworks/av/media/libstagefright`. Can you please ensure that `MxDataSource` is placed after `MediaSource` and that `MediaSource.cpp` compiled without any issues?

Comment: Thanks again Ganesh for taking interest. I'v added header you mentioned. Apart from that, after googling a lot I found a flag -fno-rtti. Do you know anything about that? When I added APP_CPPFLAGS += -fno-rtti in Application.mk, my compilation error is resolved. I do not know whether it is right or not. The key words I found on Net while searching for this solutions are 'virtual', '-frtti', 'type-casting' etc. The above class has virtual functions, derived from MediaSource. When I used -frtti instead of -fno-rtti, error remains the same. Any idea on this?

Comment: I haven't encountered `APP_CPPFLAGS`. I have integrated a new parser, but my modifications were limited to `media/libstagefright` folder and adding the relevant files to `Android.mk`. In your comment, you mention about `Application.mk`. Can you please share more details on where you are trying to include your parser file? Is it under `frameworks/av/media/libstagefright` (assuming **JB**) or some other folder? Please share more details about your setup.

Comment: I am trying to develop an android application which can be installed on all android phones. So, I have created a project in eclipse with jni directory in which I am defining Android.mk and Application.mk files and my source files. In the same jni directory, I have added all the include files and directories, required for stagefright. Currently my libstagefright.so and all headers are retrieved from Android ICS build. The flag APP_CPPFLAGS is added   in Application.mk under jni directory of my project. Let me know if we are thinking on different direction.

Comment: Aaah... this is the difference. I was trying to add a new `DataSource` under `frameworks/av/media/libstagefright` folder. Your requirement seems to be more at `JNI` layer. It would be nice to know if you could consider moving `MxDataSource` under `libstagefright` folder.

Comment: can i distribute my custom libstagefright to all device? because i want to develop device independent app. can i achieve this indepence using libstagefright.so ? is this t

Comment: can i distribute my custom libstagefright to all device? because i want to develop device independent app. can i achieve this indepence using libstagefright.so ? is this the stable library?

Comment: To develop a new parser, I feel it is always better to integrate the same as part of `libstagefright.so`. More often than not the parser would be running on the host processor of your platform which will be the same across all devices. In general it's a pure `C++` code which can run across multiple platforms, similar to other parsers like `MPEG4Extractor`. Of course, you do need to consider the licensing and legal aspects of distributing the sources, which is true irrespective of you distributing as a standalone app or as part of `libstagefright.so`

Comment: Excellent!!! Based on your direction what I am thinking is what if I can customize libstagefright.so and rename it like libabcstagefright.so and pack it in my apk to distribute through android play store (Ya, legal maters will be take cared). If one is installing that application than the actual libstagefright.so of his phone will be remain as it is. But my application will run using my libabcstagefright.so, available in my .apk file. So What do you say about this? All I want is to use libstagefright for my customization on all android phones.

Comment: Yes.. your idea seems to be fine..

Comment: @sam18.. what did you decide for the final solution..

Comment: For the 'typeonfo' error, as I commented, I added flag -fno-rtti in application.mk and this solves my problem. uptill now, I diden't find any problem with that. I guess stagefright is compiled with the same flag, due to which my code is not compiled with -frtti (which is probably the default flag for ndk cpp files). And for the matter of my custom distribution of stagefright, I haven't give it a try yet. But will check soon.

Answer (score 1):

Are you linking to MediaSource which is precompiled in a library? It appears MediaSource was compiled using -fno-rtti which might be why adding -fno-rtti fixes it. Does Android provide libsupc++ runtime support? I'm not an android developer...

Comment: Ya, That can be the reason why it works with -fno-rtti. I linked libstagefrighed.so.